Using loadChildren and loadComponent for lazy loading together in AppRoutingModule
I am using Angular 18 with modules as well as standalone components.
In my AppRoutingModule I want to lazy load my standalone components as well as my modules with with loadComponent() and loadChildren().
But if I navigate to a lazy component route /lazyComponent and then refresh the page, after the page refreshes, the component is not loaded.
I use bootstrapModule() in main.ts.
Is it even possible or do i have to transform my modules to standalone components, too and then using bootstrapApplication()?
My code in AppRoutingModule looks like:
{
        path: 'orders',
        loadComponent: () => import('./orders/orders.component').then(m => m.OrdersComponent)
    },
    {
        path: 'addresses',
        loadChildren: () => import('./addresses/addresses.module').then(m => m.AddressesModule)
},

Also if I use
{
        path: 'lazyComponent',
        component: LazyComponent
},

without lazy loading, refreshing the page doe not load the component.
main.ts:
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));



Make sure you have basehref added in index.html.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My app</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <base href="/">
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  </body>
</html>


base href already exists

@builderfan please share stackblitz or github repo with the issue  happening for debugging
